# Python Comments UnicodeDecodeError

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am getting following error message when checking the python file in Python 3.6:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8f in position
>   32649: character maps to

The position is a python script **comment** line containing special characters "ハ". I have header "# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-" added to my python script.

The same script is checked successfully in Python 2.7 but throwing error in Python 3.6. Am I missing anything to do in the migration?

**EDIT:**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

class TestClass():
    def TestCase(self):
        """ Description: 
        * name "ウユェア".
        * name "ドユウハ".
        * names "ェアハード", "ハウユード".
        """
        print("test")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    testclass = TestClass()
    testclass.TestCase()
```

`Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Program Files\Python36\Lib\site-packages\Pythonwin\pywin\framework\intpyapp.py", line 335, in OnFileCheck
     scriptutils.CheckFile()

File "C:\Program Files\Python36\Lib\site-packages\Pythonwin\pywin\framework\scriptutils.py", line 467, in CheckFile
     code = f.read() + "\n"

File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
     return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0] UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8f in position 158: character maps to <undefined>`

Comment: Are you using windows? If so have you try to change the code page? https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/4677

Comment: Can you try to strip you script to a [mcve] containing the headers and the comment so as we can reproduce the problem?

Comment: Can you show a hex dump of the problematic bytes?  Copy/pasting your problem character gives me [U+30CF](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/30cf/index.htm) which is 0xE3 0x83 0x8F in UTF-8. The error message looks like one or the other of the first two bytes is somehow dropped or missed.

Comment: Also, can you update the trace so it pertains to exactly the file you are showing as an example? I can't repro on Python 3.5.1.

Comment: Cannot reproduce with Python 3.6.2, when source file is correctly UTF-8 encoded. Did you double check source file encoding?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
file = open(filename, encoding="utf8")
```

Comment: The error is in python script comment. I am not reading any file.

Answer (score 0):

Please post part of your script where you face that error also try this.

`export PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8`